# To convert 3d model from obj,3ds to .ac file format

Tags: 3d-model

I am having a 3d model of a car in .3ds format.I want to convert .3ds/.obj files into .ac format. Is there any tool to do this?

Comment: have you tried blender? i bet there are plugins for these formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution.

Blender (http://www.blender.org/) can open .3DS and .OBJ formats.

> ### File Formats
>
> Blender comes packed with import/export support for many different programs.
>
> - **3D**
>
>   3D Studio (3DS), COLLADA (DAE), Filmbox (FBX), Autodesk (DXF),
>     Wavefront (OBJ), DirectX (x), Lightwave (LWO), Motion Capture (BVH),
>     SVG, Stanford PLY, STL, VRML, VRML97, X3D.

And [this AC3D Exporter plugin](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.4/Py/Scripts/Export/AC3D) for Blender will allow you to export to .AC.

> Export selected meshes to AC3D's .ac file format.